# Wilcoxon signed rank test with statsmodels.stats.stattools.stats.wilcoxon(x)

Tags: python-2.7, statsmodels

I want to do a one sided test with one sample.
Therefore I inserted the difference of the sample vector and the 
median to test for.

```
x = samplevector - testmedian
T, pval = statsmodels.stats.stattools.stats.wilcoxon(x)
```

For converting from two-sided to one-sided test:

```
p_one_sided = pval / 2
```

I tested to cases: 1) sample has testmedian, 2) sample has a different testmedian

When calculating 1) I obtained large values for p and the teststatistic.
When calculating 2) I got very small p and teststatistic. 
Shouldn't this be the other way - the more different the sample from the testmedian,
the larger the values of p and teststatistic?

Comment: Can you show in an example what you actually did. If you subtract the median from the sample, then the test will most likely not be able to reject that the mean rank is zero since you already centered the variable, and therefore have a high p-value.

Comment: testcase 1) I calculated (via excel) a random sample with mean=zero. testcase 2) I constructed via excel a random sample with mean significantly different from zero. In both cases I tested, if the obtained sample vector 1) or 2) has a median=0 (I called it testmedian).  1) results in a centered variable, 2) is not centered, because sample median is different from testmedian (zero).

Comment: Then everything looks as expected, large p-value and don't reject in the first sample (null is correct), and small p-value and reject in the second case (null is wrong in generated data).

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test null hypothesis is rejected when T < Tkrit. Does the statsmodels test calculate T or Tkrit. I assumed it's T. However, the calculated value goes to zero for samples having a mean different from zero.

Comment: I was talking about the interpretation of p-values. See point 6 in test procedure in the Wikipedia page for the test statistic z or W. Scipy.stats.wilcoxon uses z.

Comment: it says If z > z_{critical} then reject H_0 with H_0 being sample is centered.